# Trying to modify a modem firmware squashfs

Tags: squashfs

Good Day,

I'm trying to modify a greenpacket modem firmware.
The firmware is a `.tar.gz`

I was able to extract it and
the files are  `format.txt`, `initrd`, `md5.txt`,  `umac`, `zImage`

I extracted the `initrd` using firmware mod kit using the `unsquashfs-all.sh` command.

Then I modified the firmware after that I remade it using

```
./mksquashfs squashfs-root initrd
```

Then put it back on the folder and compressed it again using tar.gz. But when I uploaded it on the modem an error appeared saying `/tmp/image` file not compatible. Hope you can help me. I can upload the firmware if you want to.